# htaccess gives 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a WAMP server running, but as long as I have a copy of the .htaccess file, it gives me the 500 error, even when .htaccess is a blank file or with `RewriteEngine off` in it.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: [Sun Oct 24 13:50:44 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.

Comment: [Sun Oct 24 13:50:44 2010] [notice] Child 2676: Child process is exiting

Comment: [Sun Oct 24 13:50:28 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/httpd-2.2-x64/htdocs/favicon.ico

Comment: should the htaccess have something if it's supposed to be rewriting and php try is trying to use something it could result in a 500 error check your php logs

Comment: apache error log:   [Sat Apr 12 17:16:18 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/wamp/www/app/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed on Apache? I.e: enabled rewrite_module in WAMP manager?

Comment: Yes it is enable LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: After enabling it i get this error on log [Sat Apr 12 17:25:54 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/wamp/www/app/.htaccess: DocumentRoot not allowed here

Comment: Please don't flood comments with log data, which is hard to read anyway. You should *edit* the question and post the relevant info there.